# Can we do Istikhara twice for something?

Tags: istikharah

Based on my researches, in the Urf (custom or tradition of the society), Istikhara often/always is done once for everything. Some days ago, a friend of mine did a Istikhara for doing something (to take trip to a specific country), and the result of Istikhara was bad/negative for his travel.

Some days later -- after his negative Istikhara -- he decided to do another Istikhara (in order to have [perhaps] a positive result of Istikhara to allow him to take trip!). It seems he insist on this travel and as if he want to do his another chance by Istikhara (!) to take the consent of Allah for travelling!

But, my 2 questions are:

**Is it permissible/halal to do a/the second Istikhara in sth whose first result of Istikhara was negative? (In order to get a positive result?)**

**What will happen if somebody do against Istikhata's result?**

---

**Note**: Both Shia and Sunni viewpoint would be appreciated.

Comment: The sunni perspective should have been covered in answers on the site (the answer is yes it is lawful).

Comment: Uh-huh, may be. The answer is yes it is lawful? right, I appreciate your informative comment (plus congratulation of moderator...). Anyhow, I hope I found related/complete answers, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **sunni perspective** says one my redo [istikhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salat_al-Istikharah), as often as one wants -I found no clear evidence for that except for the vague wording of the related [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/19)-. I have not found any limitation so far, especially for the case one had a bad or negative result. So maybe this part needs some further research.
There are two supporting evidences for this practice however:

In sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/131):

> ...When he prayed, he prayed thrice, and when he asked for God's blessings, he asked thrice. Then he said thrice: ...

and a da'if hadith where the prophet() might have recommended his companion Anas () to repeat istikhara seven times.

This fatwa on islamqa [#11981](https://islamqa.info/en/11981) offers many answers and details on the topic of istikhara from sunni perspective.

The **shi'a perspective** according the marji' [al-Sistani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Sistani) is quoted in a few answers here on [www.sistani.org](https://www.sistani.org/arabic/qa/0310/) - My own translation take it carefully- in the Q&A 1, 4:

> السؤال: هل يجب علي المستخير الالتزام بالاستخارة؟ وهل يجوز له اعادة الخيرة بعد مضي وقت؟
>   Question: Does the person doing istikhara needs to abide to the result? And is it allowed to re-do istikhara after a time gap.
>   الجواب: ينبغي العمل بموجبها ولا تعاد الا بتبديل الموضوع ولوبالصدقة.
>   Answer: One is asked to abide to the result and shouldn't repeat it, only if one changed the reason or situation, for example by a sadaqah.

In fatwa or Q&A #11 he explains that the sadaqah is meant to be done before a second Istikhara, if the first ended with no clear result, and in:

> السؤال: هل يجوز الأستخارة على نفس الموضوع اكثر من مرة بغية الحصول على نتيجة ايجابية وبأيها يؤخذ؟ (اي بالأولى ام بألاخيرة)؟
>   Question: Is repeating istikhara for the same "Topic" more than once with the intention of gaining a positive result allowed, and if so what result should one follow? (The first or last?)
>   الجواب: لا معنى لتجديد الإستخارة لموضوع واحد إلاّ اذا تغيّرت بعض الظروف أو مضى زمان بحيث يحتمل تغّير المصالح والمفاسد.
>   Answer: There's no sense in repeating Istikhara for the same reason, only if the circumstances have changed and time has passed in a way that one may suppose that the benefits and abuses have changed

Note that in the fatwas or Q&A #12 and #13 addressing not abiding to Isitkhara al-Sistani allows it in case of a good/positive result (#12) and in case of a bad result (#13) he allows a sadaqah by dhabihah (zabihah), saying that this might not change the what was prescribed for that person in case of not abiding to the Istikhra result.

So according to shi'a view repeating Istikhara needs a change of the circumstances after a certain time, else it is meaningless.

**Differences in Term or practice**

Also note that even if the topic of Istikhara and the purpose seems to be the same for both sunni and shi'a there are clear differences, while sunni have clear and specific ally formulated du'a which is performed after an optional prayer. Shi'a have other options as I could conclude on the answers about Istikhara or Khiyara of the marji' al-Sistani, for example doing Istikhara with a-sabaha (Q&A 6), Isitkhara is only recommended if there is a doubt and one has nobody to ask for guidance on the matter(Q&A 7, 8,9) (sunni's recommend it, but one still may do Istikhara nevertheless), Istikhara via qur'an and the prayer of it which seems to be called the prayer Patches or Palm leaves صلاة الرقاع where one may write on six "papers" (or equal) 3 times "do it" and another 3 times "don't do it" ...

Comment: It looks an informative answer, particularly it contains both Shia and Sunni perspective. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                   بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

I myself researched in several Islamic (Shi’a) sites, and totally concluded the following elucidation:

Of note, my answer is based on Shia Islam perspective. Firstly, generally, let’s see when Istikhara is taken? In short: When you intend to do a (significant) affair, at first, you think/evaluate it, if you still have hesitation then you (should) consult relevant aware person(s); if you are still in doubt, then/eventually you ought to go to the last stage (taking Istikhara).

**Regarding repeating the Istikhara: it can be repeated if the subject/circumstances have changed (and it is said if a remarkable time has passed + giving Sadaghah (charity)…). Actually, the repetitions of Istikhara ought to have a logical justification.** (not based on what like to reach in!)

Meanwhile, note that it is not Wajib (compulsory) to practice in Istikhara but it is better not to do against that. (I conclude that wise individuals never do against it, since otherwise as a rule of thumb they’ll incur a loss –physically/spiritually--), and it can be regarded as a kind of disrespecting that we don’t do His consultation/advice, can’t it?!)

---

But, in regards to the last part of the inquiry as asked

> What will happen if sb do against Istikhata's result?

**If somebody will do against the denoted result of Istikhara, subsequently, the likely/definite (bad) consequences of such disobeying will be with himself!**

---

Reference:

[http://old.aviny.com/quran](http://old.aviny.com/quran/estekhareh/Adab/Porsesh.aspx)

[www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/11050/%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%88-%D8%AC%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C) and [rasekhoon.net](http://rasekhoon.net/faq/show/502359/%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A8/)

[www.yjc.ir/](http://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/5704275/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%B9%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AA%DB%8C) + my assumption/perception of that.