# Is it must to follow a negative result after praying istikhara

Tags: dua, relationships, istikharah

Assalamu aleykum
I had relationship with a boy for nearly 2 years.  We chose each other for our deen and planned to get married. Alhamdulilah our parents accepted.

Within our relationship we had misunderstandings and conflicts but I was always the one who used to apologize first. Finally he decided to pray istikhara, he prayed for 7 days and he told me the result he felt was negative and he decided break-up with me.

I was so unhappy heart broken and told him to not leave me Allah will give us the best I did everything but he is saying his istikhara was negative and he will not disobey Allah for the feeling he showed.

Please advise on what I can do. I pray every night salatul leyl and make dua.

Comment: See for example [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46471/isthikarah-questions), [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44728/can-we-do-istikhara-twice-for-something) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34907/istikihara-result-negative).

Comment: What I infer is the relationship is wrong in sight of Allah. Only when there is a wali you can communicate to that person for marriage. Aisha was offered by his father abu bakr for marriage.